# How to build strategy for particular setup of kafka

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I have three applications let named AppA, AppB, AppC. All could have several some message queue named like

```
AppA
   MsgQueueA
   MsgQueueB 
AppB
   MsgQueueA
   MsgQueueB 
   MsgQueueC
AppC
   MsgQueueA
   MsgQueueB 
   MsgQueueD
```

I have very little exposure for Apache Kafka and even for message queue concepts.

I just thinking to create topics for MsgQueueA, MsgQueueB and so on. But I am confused how to integrate AppA, AppB, AppC. Partition and Consumer group look like wrong choices for them.

Also If separation of queue/topic for Apps is better idea instead of re-using them for different Apps for better debugging Like below

```
AppA
   AppAMsgQueueA
   AppAMsgQueueB 
AppB
   AppBMsgQueueA
   AppBMsgQueueB 
   AppBMsgQueueC
AppC
   AppCMsgQueueA
   AppCMsgQueueB 
   AppCMsgQueueD
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you want to do? Do you want to send messages between AppA, AppB and AppC?

A good starting point is to have a topic for a certain "type" of message: e.g. AppA collects information about exchange-rates and wants to publish this information to AppB and AppC than you would have a topic exchange-rate where AppA produces (sends) messages to and AppB and AppC consumes (read) messages from.

Comment: @TobiSH, No All three applications are independent. They all sample core application with each having specialized features. So most of my message queue will be exists in all three, But some may be added or removed for each one. All three send there message to Message Queue server through producer script and then consumer script will consumer them. producer & consumer script is written for each application.

Comment: Can you please explain your use-case? You can put message to a queue to consume it "somewhere else". The kafka-server provides centralized queues (aka topics). This topics are organized in partions. If you read events from a kafka-broker you use some-called consumer. You can add several consumer-instances to one consumer group. An event or a message is consumer only once within a consumer-group. Does that helps you?